# Navigation buton ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple static htmls stored in the /Content/ file. I have a method in the controller which displays these static html files.

```
public ActionResult GetHTML(int sectionId)
    {
        var result = new FilePathResult($"~/Content/files/{sectionId}.html", "text/html");
        return result;
    }
```

I have no view for this method, but I'd like to create one and to include a button which allows me to navigate to the next/previous static html.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Create/Return a GetHtmlViewModel, and for example add a property Payload {get; set;} and Html.Raw it in the view Created by GetHtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regular view with a FilePathResult as its model.
If the model is not null in the view then you can create a hyper link in the view from result:

```
<a href="@Model.FileName">Next Page</a>
```

Comment: so basicly without protection we can query/gues/bruteforce every sectionId and see whats up